# ruby assign variable from system in apache server?

Tags: ruby, apache, cgi

Im trying to test this command for export a system variable to ruby in my cgi server  but not works

```
system({"MYVAR" =>  mk,  "baz" => varpage2}, 'uuid=$(convert  "$baz$MYVAR.png"   -sample 100%    -alpha remove -define connected-components:verbose=true  -connected-components -4 -auto-level     ccr3edsult.png  ); export  uuid')
m=""
File.open("uuid", "w") do |f|  f.puts ENV["uuid"].inspect  end
```

Please help me

Comment: May you tell us more about this? Are you getting an error? do you have a log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Environment variables are not a good fit for this use case because the calling program can never see the environment of the called program.

You can use backticks to get the output of a program instead:

```
File.open("uuid", "w") do |f|
  f.puts `convert #{Shellwords.escape(varpage2 + mk + ".png")} -sample 100% -alpha remove -define connected-components:verbose=true -connected-components -4 -auto-level ccr3edsult.png`
end
```